# Cannot resolve SphericalUtil

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to compute area of a polygon by `SphericalUtil.computeArea()` method but getting cannot resolve symbol `SphericalUtil`.

I have put the following line in `gradle.build`

`compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'`

Comment: try using a specific version instead of 0.4.+ try 0.4.2 or something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
```

That is not a valid dependency because there is a `.` between the `4` and the `+`, hence it cannot be resolved.

As is said on [their official website](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/), you should use this instead

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```

without that extra dot.

Then you can use it with this import

```
import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil;
```

Comment: When i created new map activity then it added a dot automatically. What could be the reason?

Comment: @user2301309 how did you create a new map activity?

Comment: I just created a java class and then extend FragmentActivity after that I did further coding.